# What is the alternate of numpy.digitize() function in Julia?

Tags: julia, bins

I would like to know, how may I replicate the `numpy.digitize()` functionality in julia?
I am trying to convert this python example to Julia.

## Python Example

```py
x = np.array([0.2, 6.4, 3.0, 1.6])
bins = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 10.0])
inds = np.digitize(x, bins)

Output: array([1, 4, 3, 2], dtype=int64)
```

I tried using `searchsorted` function in Julia but it doesn't replicate the output form python.
Please suggest a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `searchsortedlast` with broadcasting:

```
julia> x = [0.2, 6.4, 3.0, 1.6]
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.2
 6.4
 3.0
 1.6

julia> bins = [0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 10.0]
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
  0.0
  1.0
  2.5
  4.0
 10.0

julia> searchsortedlast.(Ref(bins), x)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 4
 3
 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was putting bins directly and not broadcasting over the array (beginner mistakes :P)
Highly appreciate your response!!